# how to generate .m file in mathematica without (**); Run the mathematica script on HPC

Tags: high-performance-clusters, run

For example, I write a simple script in Mathematica like this: `x = 4; y = 5; x*y`. I want to get the output of `x*y`.
I saved it as an .m file. But when I opened the file, it showed

```
(* ::Package:: *)
(* ::Input:: *)
(*x=4;y=5;x*y*)
```

Why there is `(**)`?
If there is `(**)` in the code, the inner script will not run, right?

Comment: You need to use Code cells then.

Comment: Thanks Kuba. And how to Code cells? Could you write a simple example for me. I searched a lot on Google, but I can't find a suitable example for me. Thank you very much

Comment: It should be the default cell in .m files. If you use .nb then Alt+8 will create new / covert selected to code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. I used Alt+8, which created a gray cell. Then I copied the code in that cell and saved as .m file. The code in the gray cell will not covered with (**)

Comment: But there is still the default code like (* ::Package:: *) and (* :: Input:: Initialization:: *). I still do not understand it and how it works clearly.  I need to read the help of mathematica. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you created a notebook, wrote something in it, then used File -> Save As... and chose "m. file"?

First of all, if you are looking for create a plain text Mathematica script (.m file or .wl file), it is best not to use notebooks at all. Create an .m file directly, and edit that.

---

That said, if you need to save a notebook as an .m file, only "initialization cells" will be included. Cells may be marked as "initialization cell" individually, or in groups. Check Cell -> Cell Properties. Some cell types, such as `Code` cells, have the "initialization cell" property by default. `Input` cells do not.

A simple way to add the initialization property to many cells at once is to place them under a `Section` heading (add a `Section` cell type above them), select the cell group, and add the "initialization group" property to it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. And how to set a Section heading. It seems that there is no Section command.

Comment: @YueYu Format -> Style -> Section, after having placed the input cursor inbetween cells (not inside of a cell). Or use Alt-4 (Win/Linux) or Command-4 (Mac).